# Question about scripting closed as not being related to programing

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, close-reasons

[This question about autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506736/can-autohotkey-toggle-keymapping) was closed as off-topic.

programing: (from dictionary)

1. A set of coded instructions that enables a machine, especially a computer, to perform a desired sequence of operations.
2. An instruction sequence in programmed instruction.

The question was closed as:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they **directly involve tools** used primarily for **programming**.

The tool directly involved was the autohotkey scripting language and it was used for programing (it involved code, a set of coded instructions).

Was this question correctly closed?

Note that autohotkey is a tool used for mapping keys, but that does not mean that it is limited in that way. It is actually a very powerful scripting-language capable of doing practically anything.

Great script examples done with autohotkey:
http://www.autohotkey.net/~polyethene/

Comment: This seems on topic to me. I'm afraid it was probably closed because it might sound like it's about windows (as in, 'how do I map a key' and not programming). I voted to reopen

Comment: aaand... it's reopened.

Comment: It's on topic - I just voted to reopen